# What are each of the executables in msys2 used for?

Tags: msys

When I install `msys2` using scoop.  I noticed there are a few executables in the base folder.

mingw32.exe
mingw64.exe
msys2.exe
msys2_shell.cmd

but I can't understand as to why there are a few of them or what is different between each of these "pinned launchers"

https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Launchers/
https://github.com/msys2/msys2-launcher

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1):

This
https://www.msys2.org/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin/
...  seems to sum it up in a few short lines.

It all depends on "what you wish to do", i.e. which version of related software to use.
The end result of course depends of these.

Quoted:

```
MSYS2 uses Pacman (known from Arch Linux) to manage its packages and comes with three different package repositories:

    msys2: Containing MSYS2-dependent software
    mingw64: Containing 64-bit native Windows software (compiled with mingw-w64 x86_64 toolchain)
    mingw32: Containing 32-bit native Windows software (compiled with mingw-w64 i686 toolchain)
```

Which one to actually use, depends on what you're trying to achieve and where you wish to use the resulting software.

Comment: I'm trying to set it up for this closed question https://superuser.com/questions/1601890/how-do-you-set-up-msys2-to-work-like-git-for-windows-but-with-zsh

Comment: git is for keeping track of versions of files. which git you use shouldn't matter much.

Comment: seems to, because I found the git with msys2 does not have credential manager and flags files as modified when they are not.  All because git for windows developers do not want to add 2MB to the install image.  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2023#issuecomment-455644182